# How send another POST from inside a POST

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to send a POST but I am getting an empty post on my other script.
What I am doing wrong?

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $url = 'http://localhost:3000/post';

    $data = $_POST;

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}
```

This is for sync between 2 apps.
When I replace

> $data = $_POST;

by

```
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
```

Works like a charm!

Thanks!

Comment: What results are you getting? Any error messages or other output?

Comment: No error. Just receiving an empty post.

Comment: You might try testing the second POST using a smaller set for `data`, maybe just a couple of name/value pairs. Make sure that is working first.

Comment: Are you using a form with this also?

Comment: Jonathan,  I've done it. I've updated the post.

Comment: Fred, yes. The $_POST is comming from wordpress when we add, edit, delete new posts.

Comment: If your form's elements are not named, then that could be the or a reason.

Comment: It's wordpress form. So it's named. This code is inside post.php on wp-admin on wordpress.

Comment: I'm surprised it's not working, considering changing $data = array(...) works. In that case I'd give in and do something like foreach( $_POST as $key=>$value ) { $data[$key] = $value; }

Comment: Can you update the question with a `var_dump` of `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some how, wordpress was deleting the $_POST at some point and after I've moved up my code to the top of the file, the problem was resolved.
Thanks you all!